# Need help keeping a relative path when recursing through an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array of folders/files that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Root Folder 1] => Array
        (
            [Sub Folder 1] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file 1.txt
                            [1] => file 2.txt
                        )
                )

            [Sub Folder 2] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file.txt
                        )
                )

            [Sub Folder 3] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file.txt
                        )
                )

        )

    [Root Folder 2] => Array
        (
            [Sub Folder 1] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file.txt
                        )
                )

            [Sub Folder 2] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file.txt
                        )
                )

            [Sub Folder 3] => Array
                (
                    [:files:] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file.txt
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Basically, the I have folder names as the keys and within the folders, there is a `:files:` key that contains a list of all files within that folder.

What I'm having trouble with is creating a 'full path' to that file when echoing at the array data. For example, I need paths to look like this:

```
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\file 1.txt
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\file 1.txt
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 2\file1.txt
```

My current function looks like this:

```
function format_tree($array, $map, $currentPath=null)
{
    if (!is_array($array))
        return;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key != ':files:')
        {
            $currentPath = $currentPath . DS . $key;

            echo '<div class="folder"><span style="display: block; font-weight: bold" title="' . $currentPath . '"><span>' . $key . '</span></span><div class="contents">';

            format_tree($value, $map, $currentPath);

            echo '</div></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++)
            {
                $path = $currentPath . DS . $value[$i];
                echo '<span class="file" style="display: block" title="' . $path . '"><span><a href="/public/uploads/' . $path . '" target="_blank">' . $value[$i] . '</a></span></span>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with it is the `$currentPath` never gets 'reset' when you leave a directory. This results in paths like this:

```
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\file 1.txt
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\file 1.txt
Root Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\Sub Folder 2\file1.txt
```

As the current key in the array (folder name) gets appended to the old directory path.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to echo some html in a function . This one will generate an array containing those paths you wanted. It's also able to iterate over deeper nested arrays. Magic of recusion :)

```
function getfiles($paths, &$files = array(), $currentPath = '') 
{

    foreach ( $paths as $key => $path )
    {
        if ( $key == ':files:' )
        {
            foreach ( $path as $file )
            {
                $files[] = $currentPath . '/' .$file;
            }
            continue;
        }
        getfiles($path, $files, $currentPath . '/' . $key);
    }
    return $files;
}

// usage example, $paths is the array holding the nested structure

$list = array();
getfiles($paths, $list);
var_dump($list);
```

Comment: That works great! Just tried it out and all paths look good. One slight problem is how I would output that data in a folder/file tree view. In my original function, I knew what was a folder and what were files. This allowed me to create the appropriate indents to see, visually, what files were in what folders. Your function just spits out an array of paths, which is good, but how can I now see the tree of paths rather than a simple list of paths?

Comment: I spent a couple minutes on it and I've got my tree view. You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks a lot :}

Comment: sorry i was out for a smoke. such nice words i've never heard here before. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/') + 1);
```

this should remove the last subfolder from the path string.

Comment: may need to tweak depending on if the path has a trailing slash or not. you would want to add an offset of 1 to the strrpos in that situation i think.

Comment: How do I check whether or not the last subfolder needs to be removed? If on the second iteration (now in `Root Folder\Sub Folder 1`), I would end up echoing out the file paths like: `Root Folder\file 1.txt`

Comment: you can tell if you are on the last iteration by doing something like this http://blog.actsmedia.com/2009/09/php-foreach-last-item-last-loop/

Comment: theres probably an easier wy to structure your array. maybe each folder should be an array where the first array element is an array full of filenames, and the second element is an array full of other subfolders.